# Is it possible to add some TLS cert in kubernetes-ingress?

Tags: kubernetes

Good day

Writing of this kind doesn't work, how can I add multiple certificates to cubernetis ingress?

```yaml
#not working

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - https-example1.foo.com
      secretName: https-example1-foo-com-tls
      - https-example2.foo.com
      secretName: https-example2-foo-com-tls
  rules:
  - host: https-example1.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: back-end
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: https-example2.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: back-end2
            port:
              number: 80
```

Is it okay to do this? Or is it better to create several ingresses ?

Thank everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best options are:

1. Create two ingress objects with each one with two distincts certificate `https-example1-foo-com-tls`
   `https-example2-foo-com-tls`
2. Include both subdomains in one certificate
   `*.foo.com-tls`
   which will result in the usage of one ingress object

I'd go with the second option since I'll be using subdomains, which will make it easy for me using one DNS zone under one provider, also one tracking of SSL renewal.